# Cisco VSS failure.

Tags: cisco, vss, stp

We have two 6500s running with VSS.   We have a switch with dual uplinks.  Each uplink goes to a different 6500.  If the VSL between the 6500s goes down then they both become active.  This breaks the etherchannel on the switch and it chooses one of the two switches to communicate with.    Is there a way to force the switch to communicate out a certain port and ignore spanning tree?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a way to force spanning tree to pick a specific link, since it is supposed to be a self managing protocol.

This document here provides some information regarding the VSS breakdown dual active scenario that you describe and the issues it causes.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Campus/VSS30dg/campusVSS_DG/VSS-dg_ch4.html

Your etherchannel on the downstream switch should really be LACP and therefore kill one link when the VSL breaks. See this document.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/Campus/VSS30dg/campusVSS_DG/VSS-dg_appa-configs.pdf